# How to send Image(photo) using Spring boot and web socket

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I can successfully send text-based message using spring boot and websocket. But how i send the images using websocket?

> The solution I came up is to send image as base64 string, however in that case how can i verify that base64 value is definitely image(not pdf txt file etc ...) and not larger than 5MB? (MultipartFile already provides a solution with easy way)